# How to scan cheque from android

Tags: android, image-processing, image-scanner

I am going to write an application which scan the bank's cheque and extract an information from it (e.g bank name,amount, date, signature etc). I did some goggling on it but what i found is bar code scanner and ocr scanner. Is there any way using which i can scan the cheque from an android app?? Is there any library available for it ??

It would be my pleasure if someone would suggest me anything....thanks a lot for reading :)

Comment: AFAIK, checks don't have barcodes. What about an OCR scanner app? Why can't you design one like that?

Comment: yes...i can do so..but problem is that OCR will scan all the things and give back is the plain text. I only want to extract Date, NName and amount information from it.

Comment: They all have specific formats or identifiers. Search for them in your retrieved text.

Comment: let me do the same...thanks man